# rake db:migrate not working when using ActiveRecord with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, rake, rakefile

I am trying to create a very basic Sinatra app which uses only Active Record and Sqlite3.

To be as complete as possible I am following instructions from a tutorial which states the following steps in order:

1. Create a database by putting the following code in the main app file:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter =>'sqlite3',
  :database=>'wiki.db'
)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true
end
```

2. To create the database and alter its structure create a Rakefile with the following contents:

```
require "./wadapp.rb"                                                                                    
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
```

3. Save the Rake file and run the following command in the terminal:

```
rake db:create_migration NAME=create_users
```

4. A new file will be created in `db/migrate/` called `timestamp_create_users.rb` Navigate to that file and edit with the following contents:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]                                                         
  def change
    create_table :users do |t| 
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.boolean :edit
      t.timestamps null: false
    end 
    User.create(username: "Admin", password: "admin", edit: true)
  end 
end
```

5. In the terminal run the command `rake db:migrate`.

It is this final point where the code stops working. I get no output at all to indicate a `:users` has been created and no table is accessible within the app.

I have tried rolling back etc but there is no indication a table was even created so there is nothing roll back or alter? I also tried running `rake db:create` first as some posts suggested but got the following error:

```
(in /Users/jonathonday/ruby/wad/wiki)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: The `development` database is not configured for the `default_env` environment.

Available databases configurations are:


/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:251:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:219:in `resolve_connection'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:140:in `resolve'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:187:in `resolve_config_for_connection'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:187:in `create_current'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have also run the command rake db:migrate as a root user (sudo su) and did get a different error:

```
(in /Users/jonathonday/ruby/wad/wiki)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sinatra
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/jonathonday/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

This is the order I was given the instructions in to create and build the basic database with ActiveRecord so if anything is missing or there is a better way I will be very happy to listen.

Comment: Did you create the database? Did you try rolling back? There’sa lot of unknowns here—we can’t see over your shoulder.

Comment: Apologies, please see a much more comprehensive explanation above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and I believe I found the answer to your second question, why you had to revert to an older version of Active Record (5.2 instead of 6.0).

If you look at the [sinatra-activerecord repo](https://github.com/sinatra-activerecord/sinatra-activerecord), it looks like they've deprecated ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection() and replaced it with set :database{}.

So, if you change your code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter =>'sqlite3', :database=>'wiki.db')
```

to

```
set :database, {:adapter =>'sqlite3', :database=>'wiki.db'}
```

Your code should work without having to use an older version of Active Record. At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue by uninstalling ActiveRecord 6.0.2.1 and installing version 5.2.4.

This seems to resolve all the issues and when I now run `rake db:migrate` I get the result:

```
(in /Users/jonathonday/ruby/wad/wiki)
== 20200209194032 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0008s
== 20200209194032 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0178s) =============================
```

I am not sure why this is but I will post a seperate question on that.